# how to get the persistent cookie value and session cookie value in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

Im developing ruby on rails application. I want to get the persistent cookie value and session cookie value in the application. Can any please guide me on this

I have read that request.session_options[:id] will fetch the session_id, is that the one that is usually stored in session cookie? Please guide me if my way of understanding is wrong.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In Rails, it is simple as calling the session or cookies hash.

```
# Set a simple session cookie
cookies[:user_name] = "david" 
# Read a cookie 
cookies[:user_name]  # => "david"
# Delete a key
cookies.delete :user_name
```

The same goes for `session`.
So, the information that you are looking for is probably inside one of these two.

Take a look at the examples at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm

Comment: Hi Karligen,thats the values of the cookies that we create in the applicaition code, what about a cookie that is created by application by default(like session id,we dont create and  save in cookie, the application does)

Comment: @sivasankar did you try the `session` hash instead of `cookies`? `session[:id]` for instance.