# Get browser Cookie from Rails Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I'm new rails development so my knowledge is very limited. I need to access cookie from browser to show the result from database. So is there any way, I can get the data from browser and run a database query on controller.

I know, its not the way the MVC work, first it goes to controller then view but if there any chance it would be very helpful for me.

> I can access it with view's ajax but in that case, I have to deal with javascript for all the HTML so If I could do it from controller, its life saving.

Another thing, in PHP I can get browser cookie with $_COOKIE, is there any function like that in Ruby/Rails ?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the persistent cookie value and session cookie value in rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505689/how-to-get-the-persistent-cookie-value-and-session-cookie-value-in-rails-applica)

Answer (score 2):

There's a `#cookie` method can be sent to the instance of ApplicationController, which responds an object which works like a hash object similarly. So you can read and write the cookies like this:

```
// In controllers:
def show
  redirect_to root_path unless cookies[:user_name].blank?

  cookies[:user_name] = "david"  
end

// In views(erb for example):
Hello, <%= cookies[:user_name] %>!
// => Hello, david
```

Since rails MVC pattern works as server side rendering, the cookies are only accessible after requests are sent and before the pages are rendered.

So If you want to get the cookies generated **after** pages are rendered, e.g. cookies values generated via javascript, I guess there's no other way but ajax call for that. And the same, if you wanna access the cookies from a xhr request, just sent the `cookies` method like above.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

[Stackoverflow: How to access cookies from ApplicationController (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281685/how-to-access-cookies-from-applicationcontroller-rails)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

`cookies[:user_name]`